# Laravel Docker cannot execute PostgreSQL pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, docker, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, database-restore

I'm running a **docker** container with **Laravel 5** and I have **PostgreSQL** on my machine.

Everything works perfectly, except that I have waaaay to many data on my DB and that made seeding to take about 1 hour. The workaround I came up with is to restore a backup file (data only) that would seed the database for me in about 5 min.

Awesome! But...

Laravel is running inside the docker container, and PostgreSQL is not, so when Laravel does

```
  $cmd = "pg_restore -v -U pgadmin -d $database $path";

  exec($cmd);
```

I get an error saying that there is no pg_restore to execute.

```
  sh: 1: pg_restore: not found
```

So, finally, my question is: **How can I make Laravel to be able to execute pg_restore?**

Obs: it works when also running Laravel on the machine, but I really need to solve it with Laravel on docker and postgres outside.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I editted the **docker-compose.yml** and added the following line under volumes

```
./usr/bin/pg_restore:/usr/bin/pg_restore
```

Now the error is just

```
sh: 1: pg_restore: Permission denied
```

It means now it "sees" the pg_restore command but does not have rights to execute it, since it's running inside a docker container.... how can i solve this one?

Answer (score 2):

Install the tools you need -inside- the container if you want to run them from -inside- the container.

So even though you might not want to run the database process, you still need the tools.  Install it.

Comment: I editted the docker-compose.yml and added the following line under volumes
**./usr/bin/pg_restore:/usr/bin/pg_restore**
Now the error is just

**sh: 1: pg_restore: Permission denied**
It means now it "sees" the pg_restore command but does not have rights to execute it, since it's running inside a docker container.... how can i solve this one?

Comment: I don't think 'install' means to me what it means to you.   Do you think you could slap pg_restore on a usb drive and run it anywhere?

Comment: Then please describe what do you mean.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Other answers are about installing the tools to your container. I suggest you not to do so as long as you are looking for a right way. Installing redundant tools to containers is a violation of the separation of concerns principle introduced by containers.

The usual way of resolving such problems is using the needed tools from the outside of container whenever possible, taking advantage of the ability to work over the network. And `pg_restore` enables you to do so.

---

You can run `pg_restore` from the outside of the container.

According to `pg_restore --help`, you can additionally specify host data such as hostname, port, etc. of the machine you want to run `pg_restore` against. Thus, all you need is to know the IP of your container and to have the PostgreSQL port exposed to the outside (which you already have, as far I as see).

Quick snippet:

```
pg_restore -h HOST_IP -p HOST_PORT -U USER -W PASSWORD
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would not work, since the problem itself is that the php container cannot execute pg_restore. Maybe it will work if i also follow @user2105103 's answer

Comment: It would work as long as you run `pg_restore` from the host, not the container.

Comment: As said in the question, I must run it from inside the container... It's part of the problem and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution: Install postgres on the Dockerfile. Now it's able to restore databases because the pg_restore is installed in it. 
Trigger the pg_restore command from inside the docker, but using the same parameters from the .env file for the connection.

**UPDATE:**

The migration now does

```
    $database = 'database_name';
    $path     =  __DIR__ . "/database.backup";
    $ip       = env('DB_HOST');
    $port     = env('DB_PORT');
    $passw    = env('DB_PASSWORD');

    $cmd = "PGPASSWORD=\"$passw\" pg_restore -h $ip -p $port -v -U pgadmin -d $database $path";

    exec($cmd);
```

and it's working just fine!

Comment: That is what I meant ;)